# what is difference between the following optimization method?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

when i am studying RNN while running the examples on the following site,
i would like to ask one question.

https://tutorials.pytorch.kr/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial

According to the site:

**1. Model**

```py
import torch.nn as nn

class RNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()

    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    
    self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
    self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, output_size)
    self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
  
  def forward(self, input, hidden):
    combined = torch.cat((input, hidden), 1)
    hidden = self.i2h(combined)
    output = self.i2o(combined)
    output = self.softmax(output)
    return output, hidden

  def initHidden(self):
    return torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)

n_hidden = 128
rnn = RNN(n_letters, n_hidden, n_categories)

learning_rate = 0.005
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
```

The rnn model with pytorch is like above code

**2. Training**

The problem was with this part!

According to the site, learning proceeds as follows *(in this case it worked fine)*:

```py
def train(category_tensor, name_tensor):
  hidden = rnn.initHidden()
  rnn.zero_grad()

  for i in range(name_tensor.size()[0]):
    output, hidden = rnn(name_tensor[i], hidden)
  
  loss = criterion(output, category_tensor)

  loss.backward()

  for p in rnn.parameters():
    p.data.add_(p.grad.data, alpha=-learning_rate)

  return output, loss.item()
```

But in the pytorch model I recently learned, learning proccess was carried out by `optim.step()`

So, i also tried the following method *(in this case, it didn't work well)*:

```py
optimizer = optim.Adam(rnn.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)  

def train(category_tensor, name_tensor):
  hidden = rnn.initHidden()
  rnn.zero_grad()

  for i in range(name_tensor.size()[0]):
    output, hidden = rnn(name_tensor[i], hidden)
  
  loss = criterion(output, category_tensor)
  
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

  return output, loss.item()
```

But in this case the training didn't work properly

**3. The result window**

```py
for epoch in range(epochs):
  ...
  loss = train(category_tensor, name_tensor)
  ...
```

(Result window when this method is used: it seemed learning is not progressing)

[image]

---

so what is difference between the above optimization method?
and what should i do if i want use `optim.step()`??

Thanks for reading this long post and I hope you have a good day!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different optimization methods. The first one is SGD while the 2nd is Adam.

Comment: Thank you i changed like 
`optimizer = optim.SGD(rnn.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)  `
and it woks well!!
Thanks to you, I think i can live a little longer!!

if you are not busy, may i ask if the adam optimizer should not be used when using rnn??

or is it because my rnn model is properly implemented for SGD??

Comment: You can't say which one is better without having performed a thorough hyper-parameter search. In that case I believe you were getting poor results using Adam because the learning rate you use was not optimal with Adam but was with SGD...